# Problem with connecting to a java web service running on WebSphere 6.1

Tags: java, visual-studio, web-services, websphere-6.1

I have one machine running a java web service on IBM WebSphere. It is using port 9081. I also have a client to this web service written in c#.NET. The funny thing is that I can easily reference the web service in Visual Studio 2005 (I get the wsdl definition) by `http://ip_address:9081/ProjectName/services/MyService?wsdl` but I cannot call any of the exposed remote methods. I get an error saying :

> {"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9081"}

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: I got this exception earlier because of the firewall and there may be ton of other reasons too... check the firewall and see

Comment: But why would a firewall pass one request and block the other both using the same port?

Comment: Can you mark the questions as answered ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The solution was so simple. The the 'localhost' was defined in the wsdl file :). Once I had replaced it with a proper server address it started working.